# how to call a function of another file without including that file

Tags: php

I have one class suppose A and another class B in two different file A.php and B.php respectively.

How can I call function of class A in file B.php without including A.php file in B.php.

Can we call using static function?

I have seen one application in which they are not including file nor extends but using another file class function.

can we use static property for that I tried but not working any idea.

they are also not using autoload function

https://docs.google.com/a/artifex-online.com/file/d/0B6ta7daai0cYeEs0TEJ4OGRacVU/edit?usp=sharing

please have a look to these file.

see the database class used in user class.

Comment: why are you not using include() ? any specific reason?

Comment: Please describe reason so any one can understand your problem.

Comment: I have updated problem with more detail

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You'll probably get a function not defined error.

What you *can* do, and what most modern frameworks do, is use autoloading. But you need to use classes for this.

On php.net: http://php.net/autoload

As per usual, don't look at the code samples on php.net too much, they're bad.

---

[`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) is another possibility. I would not recommend using this.

Comment: they are not using autoload function

Comment: Maybe they're using `auto_prepend_file`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file . This is server configuration though, `.htaccess` at best.

Comment: no I have downloaded the code and run on my server without any php.ini configuration, it is running properly

Comment: What about any `.htaccess` files? It's a bit hard to guess without seeing the code, any chance you can post it?

Comment: look to the files I have shared

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Even most popular IDE's show you an error whilst you reference the way how you had mentioned above..

You need to make use of the functions like [include()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) / [include_once()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) or [require_once()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).

In PHP 5+ you have function called [autoload()](https://www.php.net/autoload) which does the same as the above functions specified, but the speciality of this is that you don't need to specify the include() or require() in each and every file where you want to access the included file.

Comment: please have a look to the files I have shared.