# Calling a single function from another file without including the whole file in php

Tags: php, function, include

Is it possible to call only the specific function from another file without including whole file???
There may be another functions in the file and don't need to render other function.

Comment: without including the file how can you call the function inside it.

Comment: You can copy the function into the current file. Otherwise it wont work, how can php know the function when he doesnt get the file?

Comment: Perhaps break up the files into more modular components, such as 1 class per file.

Answer (score 2):

**The short answer is: no, you can't.**

**The long answers is: yes, if you use OOP.**

Split your functions into different files. Say you are making a game with a hero:

Walk.php

```
function walk($distance,speed){
   //walk code
}
```

Die.php

```
function die(){
    //game over
}
```

Hero.php

```
include 'Walk.php';
include 'Die.php';

class Hero(){
    //hero that can walk & can die
}
```

You may have other functions like `makeWorld()` that `hero.php` doesn't need, so you don't need to include it. This question has been asked a few times before: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626522/how-to-call-functions-in-other-files-without-including-them-with-include) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186097/how-to-call-a-function-of-another-file-without-including-that-file).

One of the possible methods outlined before is through [autoloading](http://sg3.php.net/autoload), which basically saves you from having to write a long list of includes at the top of each file.

Comment: You might want to tie your answer in with the actual question the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP it's not available to get only a little part of a file.

Maybe this is a ability to use only little parts of a file:

I have a class that calls "utilities". This I am using in my projects.

In my index.php

```
include("class.utilities.php")
$utilities = new utilities();
```

The file class.utilities.php

```
class utilities {
    function __construct() {

    }
    public function thisIsTheFunction($a,$b)
    {
        $c = $a + $b;
        return $c;
    }
}
```

And then i can use the function

```
echo $utilities->thisIsTheFunction(3,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

include a page lets say the function is GetPage and the variable is ID

```
<?php
require('page.php');

$id = ($_GET['id']);

if($id != '') {
  getpage($id);
}
?>
```

now when you make the function

```
<?php
function getpage($id){
if ($id = ''){
//// Do something
}
else {
}
}
?>
```